# Accessing Gallery pics in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to get my gallery pics in my program. And I'm able to do to same by using following code:

To open gallery:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent,1);
```

and to get result back and display selected image:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) 
{ 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode) 
    { 
    case SELECT_PHOTO:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {  
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            InputStream imageStream = null;
            try 
            {
                imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageReturnedIntent.getData());
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            selectedContactPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            setContactPicture.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(selectedContactPicture));
        }
    }
}
```

Its working fine for the first time. But if I'm selecting another picture from my gallery my app getting crashed. Please help me guys to resolve this problem.

Logcat:

```
05-08 10:45:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16782): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 10:45:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16782): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-08 10:45:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
05-08 10:45:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)
05-08 10:45:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:555)
05-08 10:45:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at com.deepsa.apps.callfaker.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:89)
05-08 10:45:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4649)
05-08 10:45:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2996)
05-08 10:45:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3043)
05-08 10:45:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:127)
05-08 10:45:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1188)
05-08 10:45:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-08 10:45:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-08 10:45:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
05-08 10:45:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 10:45:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-08 10:45:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
05-08 10:45:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
05-08 10:45:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the crash? show the `Logcat` output.

Comment: Use BitmapFactory.Options inSampleSize to load bitmaps in a more memory efficient manner See  http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: @RKN: I have added    Logcat output in my question.

Comment: show your logcat output ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, It is out of Memory error, use `inSampleSize()` to load scaled version of bitmap into memory

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) 
{ 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode) 
    { 
    case SELECT_PHOTO:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {  
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            InputStream imageStream = null;
            try 
            {
                imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageReturnedIntent.getData());
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize =8;

            selectedContactPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream,null,options);
            setContactPicture.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(selectedContactPicture));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to crop image before getting it back. Can you please help me regarding that also. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use like that

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent resultData) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);


            if (isCameraOrGallery == 2 && resultData != null) {

                Uri selectedImage = resultData.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

                uploadImagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                bitmapUploadImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uploadImagePath);
                profileImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapUploadImage);
                cursor.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }
```